# Restler returning different formats depending on final slash

Tags: restler

I am using restler with mod_rewrite and making use of the "Accept" HTTP header to return the correct resource representation. 
When making requests with the "Accept: application/json" in my production environment:

http://example.com/site/collection/1/ the response is correct and formatted as json.

http://example.com/site/collection/1 the response is correct but formatted as xml.

In my development environment both these requests return the same result formatted in json and that is the way I would like it to be.
In both environments I have the .htaccess file in place:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
<ifModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag display_errors Off
</IfModule>
```

Comment: this should not be happening, help us by letting us know what version of Restler you are using and some code to reproduce this issue at our end. If you can reproduce this issue in our live examples, just the url and steps will do